# Pass variable from Javascript webmethod call to success function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I have a button click on which i have to call a webmethod and on success of the method, i need pass the parameter "this" to the function.

```
 $(".login").click(function () {
     var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
     var id = $(parent).find(".selectbtn").attr("id");
     PageMethods.validateLogin(id, onSuccess, null);
 });

 function onSuccess(result) {
     if (result) {
         //here i need to delete the parent div, that is  var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
     }
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inline your function, so that it has access to the local variables:

```
$(".login").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var id = $(parent).find(".selectbtn").attr("id");

    PageMethods.validateLogin(id, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            // just use parent here
        }
    }, null);
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass `parent` to your `onSuccess` function:

```
$(".login").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var id = $(parent).find(".selectbtn").attr("id");

    PageMethods.validateLogin(id, function(result) {
        onSuccess(result, parent);
    }, null);
});

function onSuccess(result, parent) {
    if (result) {
        // just use parent here
    }
}
```